# C run function in another thread

Tags: c, multithreading, gtk

I have simple from written on C/gtk+ and i have function in this appliction. I need to run this function in a separate thread from gui form. Where can i see example?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/GDK_Threads.html

Answer (score 1):

Thread functions are provided by your operating system, they are not part of the C standard.

Comment: I use gtk+ framework in my app. I want to make it with GThread